# Globally changing a managed metadata term for a picture library

Tags: managed-metadata, metadata

Greetings and thank you for reading this.

I have created a spreadsheet in excel (.csv) file to import a term set to the managed metadata term store tool (This was a great and convenient discovery). I have tagged the metadata to several photos in my picture library. However, in the near future I will need to change a term to a different one.

For example a department will be changing from "College and External Relations" to "University and External Relations". When I alter the metadata in the term store tool to the updated term, and then go view the images that have been tagged with the previous term, it has not updated.

I am hoping to avoid having to go through all of my picture libraries and deleting the old tag and then changing it to the new one. Is there an alternate way to globally make this change? Is it something to do with a "TaxonomyHiddenList"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The values will update eventually.

There is a hidden list on each site which stores a list of all of the tags from the Taxonomy. A timer job runs at scheduled intervals which will update the hidden list on each site with the values from the term store.

This can take an hour or two to update across all of SharePoint,

Comment: Is there anyway to refresh this instantly?